# Lexical-binding and multiple buffers

Tags: buffers, lexical-binding

I want to use a function that is taking advantage of lexical-binding:

```
(defun comp (funcs)
  "Function composition"
  (let (f0 ff)
    (if (not funcs)
        (lambda (x &rest args)
          x)
      (progn
        (setq f0 (car funcs))
        (setq ff (cdr funcs))
        (lambda (&rest args)
          (funcall f0 (apply (comp ff) args)))))))
```

So setting `(setq lexical-binding t)` inside my buffer and calling `comp` with `(funcall (comp (list (lambda (x) (* x 3)) (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)))) 0)` gives `3` as desired.

Now I want to move `comp` to another lisp-file that gets loaded (via `load-file`) from my `.emacs` at the Emacs start-up. But then I get `(void-variable f0)` which is not what I want. I included `(setq lexical-binding t)` as a first line into `.emacs` as well as the lisp-file containing `comp` but this isn't solving my issue.

How can I resolve this without having to define my function `comp` within the same buffer were I want to call it?

Comment: See also `C-h i g (elisp)Converting to Lexical Binding`.

Comment: In short, a function which needs lexical binding must be defined in a file for which lexical binding is enabled.  (You can then *call* the function from anywhere at all.)

Comment: @phils Thanks a lot for your hints!!! Yes, you are totally right - lexical-binding is required at the definition of the function. I afraid my main issues was using `(setq lexical-binding t)` instead `;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-`. The former is not working for me...